# Can I use "Your" and "Our" in the same sentence?

Tags: compound-possessives, possessive-pronouns

Is this sentence correct or do the pronouns need to match one way or the other?

"Please join your classmates for a reception to celebrate our 25th reunion"

Comment: (assuming of course that 'our' counts as a pronoun here--adjective?) :)

Comment: "Your wish is our command", "Your comfort is our goal", "Our staff is available 24/7 for your convenience", and any number of other examples.  :-)

Comment: @EHA Neither pronoun nor adjective: determiner.

Comment: I think the thing that's confusing him in this specific case is that _our_ refers to the same group as _your classmates_. It seems like it should be _their 25th reunion_.

Comment: If you were posh you could say 'Your face or ours?'

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is grammatical. There is no rule that disallows the use of "your" and "our" in the same sentence: You can find your book in our expanded library.

Comment: I don't think he was asking a general question about these words in any context, but this particular case.